# What does 'Credentials' mean in terms of HTTP Responses and Requests?

Tags: ajax, api, http, single-page-application, credentials

everyone

A few weeks ago I had a problem passing, storing and reading cookies in an app hosted in a different domain of the API. I owned both API and SPA and I could solve the problem by adding 'credentials' both in server and client and allowing CORS for that specific origin.

Although I managed to find a solution, I still don't understand what it means.

What does credentials stand for? What is it meant to solve?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

Credentials is a general term that refers to the details about you (or your app) that are used to check that you are who you claim to be when you make a request.  A variety of different kinds of credentials could be used, and they could be passed in a variety of ways.  For example:

- They could be a session token passed as a cookie
- They could be a username and password passed using the HTTP BasicAuth mechanism.
- They could (in theory) be other things.

In the context if that article, they are referring to all of the different ways that say "I am this person" in a request ... and whether the credentials should be passed around (via the browser requests) between the various hosts / servers involved.